# django models HTML allows

Tags: python, html, django

```
from django.utils import timezone
i have this in models.py

class Poll(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_curse=models.IntegerField()
    enum=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    feedback=models.TextField()
    expiration_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

my question is:

How do I make the enum field accept characters (+255) and allow me HTML content

Comment: `CharFields` can accept characters, its unclear what you're asking

Comment: And why would you call a field `enum` when you want it to take arbitrary text?

Comment: Is only a tag, does the charField allow me to accept HTML content?

Comment: What exactly is the problem and expected output you want?

Comment: Why not use `enum=models.TextField()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want your field to accept 255+ characters as a URL so this is what you are looking for; a URL field:

```
enum = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default='')
```

Or if you are refering to html contents like say `<p>hello</P><br>` then use a text field:

```
enum = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

Note: Do not forget to update/migrate your database since you have made change to the model or just reset it.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the requirement. It works perfect